# back button hardware don't refresh page xmarin forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm developing an android app with xamarin forms.
I have a Switch in a sidebar to know if the user want to Sync data in automatic or not.
If i navigate (after changed the property's value) with Navigation.PushAsync(); it works.
If i navigate with back hardware button the property has correct value but i see the old value (false).

in MyViewModel i have add NotifyPropertyChanged("Sync") to try to force the refresh of data but it doesn't work.

There is a way to refresh the view when i click back hardware button??

Comment: It should work if you have 2-way binding. Can you share example of your code, so we can try to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to override the `OnAppearing` function of the page you are navigating back to to run your sync routine.